# Roblox Studio : CharacterAdded is not a valid member of Players "Players"

Tags: lua, roblox

i have a problem, when i launch my game, the script dont work. The script is supposed to make the character walk faster and faster every second. the script :

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local Humanoid = game:findFirstChild("Humanoid")

local function UpdateSpeed(Humanoid, Seconds)
    Humanoid.Walkspeed = Seconds
end

local function PlayerAdded(Player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = Player
    
    local Seconds = Instance.new("NumberValue")
    Seconds.Name = "Seconds"
    Seconds.Value = 0
    Seconds.Parent = leaderstats
    
    local Loop = Instance.new("BoolValue")
    Loop.Name = "Loop"
    Loop.Value = true
    Loop.Parent = Player
    
    Players.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(Character)
        Loop.Value = true
        coroutine.wrap(function()
            while true do
                if Loop.Value == true then
                    Seconds.Value += 1
                    UpdateSpeed(Character.Humanoid, Seconds.Value)
                    else
                    break
                end
                task.wait(1)
            end
        end)()
        Character.Humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
            Loop.Value = false
        end)
    end)
end

local Debounce = false

for _, v in ipairs(workspace.Zones:GetChildren()) do
        v.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = tostring(v.Name).." Minutes needed to unlock!"
        v.Touched:Connect(function(Object)
            if Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Object.Parent) then
                local Player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Object.Parent)
                local Minutes = tonumber(v.Name)
                if (Player.leaderstats.Seconds.Value / 60) >= Minutes then
                    if Debounce == false then
                        Debounce = true
                        v.Transparency = 0.5
                        v.CanCollide = false
                        task.wait(1)
                        v.Transparency = 0
                        v.CanCollide = true
                        Debounce = false
                    end
                else 
                    Player.Character.Humanoid.Health = 0
            end
        end
    end)
end
    
for _, Player in ipairs(Players:GetPlayers()) do
    PlayerAdded(Player)
end
    
Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(PlayerAdded)
```

Its say CharacterAdded is not a valid member of Players "Players"   Help me please !

I try nothings because i dont know what try

Answer (score 0):

You are detecting the character of the 'Players' class. According to the API docs here: https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Player#CharacterAdded ,
you must detect the character of the player. This means that the line:

`Players.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(Character)`

must become:

`Player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(Character)`